# Twitter Bootstrap Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website built with Bootstrap and want to make a mobile version as well. The only issue is that the layouts I want to create will differ vastly. For example.

The desktop version has a huge image on the main page in the center, whereas the mobile version would not.

Is this something I can achieve in Bootstrap or must I use other methods to provide two vastly different layouts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Responsive utility classes](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive). For example:

```
<img src="image.png" class="hidden-phone" title="Main image" />
```

This image won't be visible on a phone.

**UPDATE**

This was for old Bootstrap version, for the latest see

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 9):

The suggestion from @AlecTMH is good and it's easy to do. Your other option is to use CSS and @media queries.

You could specify different values for different screen widths, eg

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body{
  background-image: url('smartphone-background.jpg');
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body{
  background-image: url('tablet-background.jpg');
  }
}
```

or you can use the CSS property display:none; to hide an object at certain screen sizes.

All the methods work well, and some are more appropriate or easier to use in different situations.

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is in regards to Bootsrap and CSS. However, given your statement that

> The desktop version has a huge image on the main page in the center

I would consider @David Taiaroa's solution or simply serving entirely different content from the server. The [Responsive utility classes](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) use `display: none` which while hiding the image, still load it. If it's a `huge` image this could affect load times on your mobile devices (See [display: none;](http://laurakalbag.com/display-none/) by Laura Kalbag).

The utility classes work better for small content that will not have a large impact on your site's load time. For large element such as high megapixel images or even carousels of images, it's best to use media queries like @David Taiaroa suggested or to serve entirely different content altogether.